# jQuery conditional to apply styles to an element when condition is met

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I thought i had this and was easy enough but my code is not working.

This is for a WordPress site but the issue is with JS.

WP puts this fixed admin bar when logged in and it covers the header of my site (see image)

[image]

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var wpbar = $('#wpadminbar'),
      main  = $('header[role="main"]');

  if($('body').has('#wpadminbar')) {
    main.css('top','32px');
  }

});
```

I have created a fiddle here and it works http://jsfiddle.net/b2xuew16/11/

But when I try it in my dev environment I get an undefined function error (not sure if that matters) or if i'm no using the correct jQuery method to begin with.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WordPress loads jQuery in [no conflict mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers), so by default you can't use the `$` shortcut. All you need to do is create an anonymous function and pass it `$`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {

 // Rejoice! $ can be used

});
```

I'll also point out that WP adds an additional class of `.logged-in` o the body element if you're logged in, so you don't need jQuery at all, it can be done just with CSS:

```
.logged-in header[role="main"] {
    top:32px;
}
```